# Как определить ширину предзагруженной картинки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Для предзагрузки картинки используется следующий код:

```
jQuery.preloadImages = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        jQuery("<img>").attr("src", arguments[i]);
    }
};

var imagesCount = $(".zoom").length;

for (var i = 0; i < imagesCount; i++) {
    var img = $(".zoom:eq("+i+")").attr("data-image");
    $.preloadImages(img);
}
```

Как при клике на кнопку с классом zoom вывести реальную ширину картинки?
У кнопки есть атрибут data-image, содержащий путь к картинке, и картинка уже загружена.

Comment: Ну решение "в лоб". Если сама картинка есть, то её можно загрузить в невидимый блок на пару секунд и вычислить ширину блока и затем удалить его.. Иначе наверно только по метаданным, которые тоже где то нужно хранить/получать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующим образом:

```
jQuery.preloadImages = function() {         
    var images = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var img = $("<img>");
        img.attr("src", arguments[i]);
        images.push(img);               
    }
    return images;              
};

$('a.zoom').each(function(i, el) {
    var link = $(this);         
    var src = link.attr('data-image');          
    var img = $.preloadImages(src)[0][0];           
    link.click(function() {
        alert('Real width: ' + img.width + ' px');
        return false;
    });         
});
```